# Why isn't the defer working in this case on my laravel project?

Tags: javascript, deferred

I'm using a layout template to yield scripts and content as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@yield('title', 'The Gourmet')</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}">
    @yield('scripts')
</head>
<body>
    @include('layout.employee.header')
    @yield('content')
    @include('layout.footer')
</body>
</html>
```

Then in my blade.php I have the following:

```
@extends('components.layout')

@section('title')
    {{ env('APP_NAME') . ' - Reserve' }}
@endsection

@section('scripts')
<script defer>
    let dateInput = document.getElementById('reservationDate');
    alert(dateInput.value);
</script>
@endsection

@section('content')
     <input type="date" name="reservationDate" id="reservationDate" min="{{ date('Y-m-d') }}" value="{{ date('Y-m-d') }}">
@endsection
```

The input has a value, and my script works if I place it underneath my input. But when I add my script through sections, it loads the script before my html and gives an "undefined" error because my input hasn't loaded yet even though I'm using the 'defer' attribute ..

So I'm just trying to get my script to work after page load using the sections to place it in the head of my html. But it keeps loading if before it renders my html, even using the defer attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        let dateInput = document.getElementById('reservationDate');
        alert(dateInput.value);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: A good answer includes an explanation, not just code, something like what was wrong with the original code and how this solves that problem. Give someone a fish vs teaching someone to fish etc.

Comment: in some cases defer may not work , might be a browser issue , or the order of multiple script files in your project , it also affect, but using events is a good practice , rather than  relaying on attributes

Comment: Thanks, this fixed my issue. The answer above explains why I did get the error, because it has no src attribute.

Answer (score 3):

If you take a look at the [MDM web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#defer) you will notice the warning

> Warning: This attribute must not be used if the src attribute is absent (i.e. for inline scripts), in this case it would have no effect.

Comment: Yes this explains it thanks! How did I overlook that error..